# Comic story arc/issue where Deadpool is eaten by zombies and the zombies all turn into Deadpool clones

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, deadpool

I vaguely recall the details of a Deadpool comic book issue I read around 4-5 years ago. Here are a few details I remember:

Deadpool eats a load of chimichangas during a zombie apocalypse and completely sleeps through the zombie takeover.

When he wakes up, he consumes some sort of serum and lets the zombies eat him. But after eating him, all the zombies turn into Deadpool clones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The food coma is from [*Night of the Living Deadpool (2014)*](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/18469/night_of_the_living_deadpool_2014_-_present).

Synopsis for #1:

> Deadpool awakes from a food coma to find…THE ZOMBIE APOCALYPSE HAS OCCURRED! Can the Merc with the Mouth avoid becoming the Merc in their Mouths? Writer of the DEADPOOL KILLOGY Cullen Bunn brings us to one of Deadpool's darkest tales ever…and not just because it's in black & white (and red)!

The zombies turning into Deadpool is his eventual solution in #4, and is explored further in the follow up series [*Return of the Living Deadpool (2015)*](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/19633/return_of_the_living_deadpool_2015_-_present).

Synopsis for #1:

> Last year, Cullen Bunn brought us NIGHT OF THE LIVING DEADPOOL, the hit tale of the Merc with the Mouth trapped in the zombie apocalypse. In the end, our hero found a "cure" of sorts to this horrible outbreak-any zombie that ate Deadpool transformed...into another Deadpool. And they lived happily ever after? Not so fast, as Cullen Bunn returns, joined by the amazing artwork of Nicole Virella, to let us know that wandering hordes of Deadpools might just be worse than flesh-hungry walking corpses.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be RETURN OF THE LIVING DEADPOOL #1:

> “So there are thousands of Deadpools, all of them originating from the one and only Wade Wilson,” says Bunn in an interview with Marvel.com. “Every time a zombie takes a bite of one of these Deadpools, the zombie becomes Deadpool. You know how Deadpool has numerous personalities? Well, these newly created Deadpools start to latch on to different aspects of Deadpools split psyche, forming factions. And these factions don’t get along!”
>
> This February, the dead will rise. And this February, the Deadpools will…er, rise! Be there for the heart-stopping, flesh-eating, wise-cracking RETURN OF THE LIVING DEADPOOL #1!
>
> [- Source, Comics Beat](http://www.comicsbeat.com/first-look-at-zombie-deadpool/)

Comment: As the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/203000/80867) notes, *Return* is the sequel to the series the OP remembers.